# Run the function of javascript in one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, formvalidation.io

Hi I have everything fine but little problem is this that functions is running one by one. I want all functions must run at one time here is the code I am using

```
<form id="payForm" action="address-to-be-licensed.html" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" onsubmit="return (fnamevalidaton() && emailvalidate() && lastnamevalidation())">
```

Comment: Where is the javascript in this code?

Comment: @SamzSakerz no need to see the JS code to answer the question but I totally agree the question is not clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help

```
<form id="payForm" action="address-to-be-licensed.html" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" onsubmit="return validate()">

<script>
    function validate() {
        var fname = fnamevalidaton();
        var email = emailvalidate();
        var lastname = lastnamevalidation();

        return fname && email && lastname;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's it Thanks a lot brother

Comment: @BlockCode you are welcome. 
Make sure you ask question clearly and with proper details, the question it self is not something you'll get minus points but it is not clear enough.